# Button Bordering in Android. Not working

Tags: android, xml, button

I need buttons with white border. And it should be filled with solid brown.
I tried but the output is like this : 
[image: Output as seen in Emulator :]

Now I dont need those white colors surrounding the buttons. Only the button should be inside the white border.The white area outside of the white border is what I need to remove.

Here's what I did.

In main.xml -

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="3" 
    android:background="#623100">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="1" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffd39b" android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="2" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffd39b" android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="3" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#ffd39b" android:textSize="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Ofcourse this is just an part of the whole main.xml file

Here's the button.xml file which I have used as background :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused"
      android:state_enabled="false" 
      />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected"
      android:state_focused="true" 
      />

</selector>
```

Here are the images used in button.xml

[image: btn_default_normal_disable_focused.9.png]

[image: btn_default_pressed.9.png]

[image: btn_default_selected.9.png]

Please help. Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: well, you set `android:background="#623100"` in your parent view in your `main.xml` layout.  I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, but that line is it.  Try changing that color value and seeing what happens.